# On Linux Min21, unable to access tools/port (grayed out)

Tags: arduino-nano, usb, linux

I have dual boot laptop, Windows 11 & Linux Mint 21 (default boot).  when running Arduino IDE 1.8.19 using Linux the port not accessible [from tools/port], but if I boot as windows, I can access the port from the Arduino IDE.

Other applications running in Linux can access the USB drive without issue (eg FreeCAD, PrusaSlicer). Arduino IDE is the only app so far with this USB issue.

"dialout" is in my list of groups

Arduino IDE was installed using apt

If I run lsusb when the nano is connected, i see the following extra entry

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
```

On another post it suggested running ls -l /dev/ttyUSB* and ls -l /dev/ttyACM*. For both I get the response "No such file or directory". The following files starting with tty* are in the /dev directory

```
tty    tty11  tty15  tty19  tty22  tty26  tty3   tty33  tty37  tty40  tty44  tty48  tty51  tty55  tty59  tty62  tty9       ttyS10  ttyS14  ttyS18  ttyS21  ttyS25  ttyS29  ttyS4  ttyS8
tty0   tty12  tty16  tty2   tty23  tty27  tty30  tty34  tty38  tty41  tty45  tty49  tty52  tty56  tty6   tty63  ttyprintk  ttyS11  ttyS15  ttyS19  ttyS22  ttyS26  ttyS3   ttyS5  ttyS9
tty1   tty13  tty17  tty20  tty24  tty28  tty31  tty35  tty39  tty42  tty46  tty5   tty53  tty57  tty60  tty7   ttyS0      ttyS12  ttyS16  ttyS2   ttyS23  ttyS27  ttyS30  ttyS6
tty10  tty14  tty18  tty21  tty25  tty29  tty32  tty36  tty4   tty43  tty47  tty50  tty54  tty58  tty61  tty8   ttyS1      ttyS13  ttyS17  ttyS20  ttyS24  ttyS28  ttyS31  ttyS7
```

If I tail the system log and plug the nano into the usb drive I get the following (the answer my be here but I cant see it).

```
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8949.381626] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8949.599105] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8949.599107] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8949.599108] usb 3-4: Product: USB Serial
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8949.601365] ch341 3-4:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8949.601888] usb 3-4: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl systemd[1]: Starting Braille Device Support...
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: BRLTTY 6.4 rev BRLTTY-6.4 [https://brltty.app/]
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: BRLTTY 6.4 rev BRLTTY-6.4 [https://brltty.app/]
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: executing as the invoking user: root
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: executing as the invoking user: root
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: CLDR open error: No such file or directory: /usr/share/unicode/cldr/common/annotations/en.xml
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: CLDR open error: No such file or directory: /usr/share/unicode/cldr/common/annotations/en.xml
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: possible cause: the package that defines the CLDR annotations directory is not installed
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: emoji substitutiion won't be performed
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: BrlAPI Server: release 0.8.3
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: possible cause: the package that defines the CLDR annotations directory is not installed
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: emoji substitutiion won't be performed
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: BrlAPI Server: release 0.8.3
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: Linux Screen Driver:
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: Linux Screen Driver:
Oct  7 17:17:14 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8950.123164] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input49
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: USB configuration set error 16: Device or resource busy
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: USB configuration set error 16: Device or resource busy
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: USB interface in use: 0 (ch341)
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: USB interface in use: 0 (ch341)
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl ModemManager[1013]: <info>  [base-manager] port ttyUSB0 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4'
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl ModemManager[1013]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4': Operation was cancelled
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8950.239032] usb 3-4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8950.239683] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl kernel: [ 8950.239693] ch341 3-4:1.0: device disconnected
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: NoSpeech Speech Driver:
Oct  7 17:17:15 HP-Envyl brltty[12613]: brltty: NoSpeech Speech Driver:
Oct  7 17:17:18 HP-Envyl rtkit-daemon[3252]: Supervising 10 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
```

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: Do you use brltty?

Comment: Uninstall `brltty`for a start.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i can close this. brtty was the problem. I disabled it (found instructions below on another post)

```
systemctl stop brltty-udev.service
sudo systemctl mask brltty-udev.service
systemctl stop brltty.service
systemctl disable brltty.service
```

After logout and login, it works now.

Thanks for the help. I did not have this issue on Mint 20, so i am guessing that brtty was automatic in Mint 21

Comment: In a couple of days you'll be able to "accept" your own post. Unless a different one shows up that you like better, you probably should.